# Why Mongo Auto Restart after Shutdown

Tags: mongodb

I tried to shut down my mongo process on a Linux server by running either `mongod.sh stop` or `mongo --shutdown`.

From the logs, I can see it `shutting down with code:0`
However, after that line, it logged `**** SERVER RESTARTED ****`, and then started a new process logging `MongoDB starting: pid=xxxxx port=xxxxx dbpath=xxxxxxxxx 64-bit host=xxxxxxxx`, which is not expected.

I tried on other instances using the same command, all of them were successfully shut down with only one line of `**** SERVER RESTARTED ****`, and nothing was logged after that.

Is there anyone knowing what possibly happened in this case? What can I do to disable this automatic restart after stopping the mongo process gracefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is installed as a service.

For stop and disable use:

```
systemctl stop mongod
systemctl disable mongod
```